# Missing xvar.h header file: Where can I find it?

Tags: ubuntu, solaris

I have some code originally written for Sun4/Solaris and it's asking for an `xvar.h` header file. The comments say:

```
/*
    The xvar.h file defines the XVAR, XINTIT, ARRAY, and comma
    macros used to either define or declare variables.
*/
#include    "xvar.h"
```

I'm trying to compile this to run on Ubuntu (via WSL, with VSCode). I have the X subsystem and the vcpkg "x11" installed, but it's still asking for the file.

Any assistance is appreciated.